# Почему vue не связывает html атрибуты

Tags: vue.js, frontend

```
<template lang="pug">
  div(:class="internalClass")
    | text
</template>

<style lang="sass">
  .classname
    color: red
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    data () { return { internalClass: 'classname' } }
  }
</script>
```

При использовании компонента

```
<v-component class="otheClass" />
```

otherClass - игнорируется (список классов перезаписывается внутри компонента)

> Приведенный пример упрощен, но решение проблемы для него, решит проблему для ниже приведенного кода (оригинала)

---

## Оригинал

```
<style lang="sass" module>
  @import '../../assets/sass/elements/link.sass'
</style>

<script>
  const state = ctx => ({
    staticClass: ctx.$style.link
  })

  export default {
    name: 'v-lnk',
    props: {
      to: { type: String, required: false }
    },
    functional: true,
    render (h, ctx) {
      return ctx.props.to === undefined
        ? <a {...state(ctx)}> { ctx.children } </a>
        : <nuxt-link to={ctx.props.to} {...state(ctx)}> { ctx.children } </nuxt-link>
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

```
<style lang="sass" module>
```

Не влияет на ошибку (проверял)

Добавление ключа 'class' в props тоже не помогает, вижу лишь один выход, завести prop 'className' и проксировать классы извне во внутрь компонента через него

```
<v-lnk className="otherClass"> Link </v-lnk>
```

Смена staticClass на 'class' тоже не влияет